# VBConversion from string "a" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
If TextBox1.Text = Strings.Right(TextBox1.Text, 1) = "a" Then

    Else
        MsgBox("suffixes must A")
    End If
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `text = strings = "a"`. you're trying to assign "a" to the RESULT of the `textbox1 = strings` call...

Comment: ty sir, i know it now

Comment: @MarcB : Actually, VB.NET doesn't support inline-assignment. What's really happening is that `TextBox1.Text = Strings.Right(TextBox1.Text, 1)` returns a boolean, then he tries to compare that against the string `"a"`, which is implicitly attempted to be converted to a bool, but fails.

Comment: @Adimas : The problem was the `TextBox1.Text = ` part. Removing it solves the problem.

Comment: Actually the fastest way of checking one character is by accessing the string's character array: `If TextBox1.Text.Chars(TextBox1.Text.Length - 1) = "a"c Then` <-- The `c` after the string means it's a char literal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
if textbox1.text = Strings.Right(Textbox1.text,1) And Textbox1.Text = "a" Then
```

If I've quite understood what you meant, should be working. Good luck, hope I've been useful!

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You're checking if the text box's entire text is equal to the last character (which will only be true if the text box contains one char), and then if the text box's text is only `a`? -- He is checking if the text is suffixed by `a`. The correct way to do so in this case is by just removing the `TextBox1.Text =` part from his original code, resulting in this: `If Strings.Right(TextBox1.Text, 1) = "a" Then`.